# Sorting an array of dictionaries by key value

Tags: objective-c

Say I have an array of 6 dictionaries- each dictionary has a "location" key with it's associated value.  How can i sort those values together so i could go from this...

```
"location" : USA
"location" : UK
"location" : Asia
"location" : UK
"location" : USA
"location" : Asia
```

to this?

```
"location" : Asia
"location" : Asia
"location" : UK
"location" : UK
"location" : USA
"location" : USA
```

Comment: It is impossible to sort key-value pair inside NSDictionary. The only way - loop through NSDictionary and store pairs somewhere,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method is what you are looking for:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"location" : @"USA"},
                   @{@"location" : @"UK"},
                   @{@"location" : @"Asia"},
                   @{@"location" : @"UK"},
                   @{@"location" : @"USA"},
                   @{@"location" : @"Asia"}];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"location"] compare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"location"]];
}];
```